# how to compute $\sum{\frac{(s+k)!}{s!k!}*x^k}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, combinations, binomial-theorem

For $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(s+k)!}{s!k!}x^k}$, $0\leq x\leq1$. It is not binomial. So how can we simplify the factorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is binomial:

$\frac{(s+k)!}{s!k!} = \frac{1}{k!}(s+k)(s+k-1)\cdots(s+1) = (-1)^k\frac{1}{k!}(-s-1)(-s-2)\cdots (-s-k) = (-1)^k\binom{-s-1}{k}$

so the sum is

$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{-s-1}{k}(-x)^k = (1-x)^{-s-1}$

Comment: But how could the number of elements in a set be negative?

Comment: The symbol $\binom{x}{k}$ just means $x(x-1)\cdots (x-k+1)/k!$, it doesn't have to have a combinatorial interpretation for the algebra to work.